# I cannot create CTE even though the query inside the CTE run successfully

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I don't know why but for some reason I cannot create a CTE.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        p1.country_code,
        (p2.gdp_per_capita - p1.gdp_per_capita) / p1.gdp_per_capita AS 'growth_percent'
    FROM 
        per_capita p1, per_capita p2
    WHERE 
        p1.country_code = p2.country_code 
        AND p1.year = p2.year - 1 
)
```

The query inside the CTE run perfectly fine but when I try to run all of this it returns this message

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Your query *literally* reads "with CTE as (...)". That's half a sentence. With CTE as (...) *do what*?  You need to write the second half.

Comment: You don't "create" a CTE - it's not an "object" - it's *part* of a query.

Answer (score 2):

You need a valid sql statement after the closing parenthesis of the CTE, most likely making use of the CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT p1.country_code,
(p2.gdp_per_capita - p1.gdp_per_capita)/p1.gdp_per_capita as 'growth_percent'
FROM per_capita p1, per_capita p2
WHERE p1.country_code = p2.country_code AND p1.year = p2.year-1 )
SELECT * FROM CTE
```